# get substring regEx

Tags: regex

How can I get from string "C27_W112_V113_Table__6__1" string "6" or from string "C27_W120_V153_Table__22__1" string "22". thx

Comment: What have you tried ? Also, is your string always ends with `__1` ?

Comment: no, last number can by 1-99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by two ways

- Regex approach:

  ```js
  const re = /(\d+)__\d+$/;
  let values = [
    'C27_W112_V113_Table__6__1',
    'C27_W120_V153_Table__22__1'
  ];
  values.forEach(str => console.log(str.match(re)[1]));
  ```
- string manipulation (I assume the value is always at the same place):

  ```js
  values.forEach(str => {
    let reversed = str.split('').reverse().join('');
    let index = reversed.indexOf('__');
    console.log(reversed.slice(index+2, reversed.indexOf('__', index+1)));
  });
  ```

Here a snippet

```js
const re = /(\d+)__\d+$/;

let values = [
  'C27_W112_V113_Table__6__1',
  'C27_W120_V153_Table__22__1'
];

values.forEach(str => console.log(str.match(re)[1]));
console.log('--------');
values.forEach(str => {
  let reversed = str.split('').reverse().join('');
  let index = reversed.indexOf('__');
  console.log(reversed.slice(index+2, reversed.indexOf('__', index+1)));
});
```